# Is that considered a converted variable to constant?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main () {
int x;
cin >> x;
const int sz = x;
int arr[sz];
for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
    cin >> arr[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++){
    cout << arr[i] << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

arr[variable] is not a standard c++, how can I fill the array size from the user? Is this considered a conversion to constant or no?

Comment: It's spelled `std::vector`

Comment: Your code shouldn't work. `const int` can only be used as array size if it's initialized with a compile-time constant expression.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I use codeblocks, and it worked. My question sz is a constant this way or variable?

Comment: @ArrayofVariable your code may compile due to available extensions to some compilers, but it is still not a valid C++ code

Comment: @ArrayofVariable Many compilers by default allow some non-standard things to work. Go to your compiler settings and add `-pedantic-errors`, and it will stop working.

Comment: @Slava What should I do if I want to fill array size from the user?

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: @ArrayofVariable you got that answer already multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are dealing with is called Variable Length Array (VLA). VLAs are (now optional) part of C standard, but not part of C++ standard. Still, many major compilers support extension which allows using of VLAs in C++.

There is a great controversy about them, with some people being forcefully opposed to those and other people (yours truly) which believe they have their place.

Comment: How can you use them in C++, when `std::end()` behavior is undefined?

Comment: @Slava it is not undefined. With compilers supporting VLAs, it is a compilation error to use `std::end` with VLAs. So the answer is: "you don't".

Comment: "With compilers supporting VLAs, it is a compilation error to use std::end with VLAs." Are you sure you checked with all available compilers?

Comment: The ones I care about, namely, gcc, clang and icc. When you venture into compiler extensions, you have to know your compiler, but it is impossible to know all of them.

Comment: Then you should not recommend to use them, as such usage can have unpredictable effects. For example OP may start to use it in a range based for loop with a compiler you do not care about.

Comment: I can hardly imagine a compiler which will accept VLA definition and still behave unpredictably with `std::end` If yours does that, file a bug report.

Comment: I can hardly imagine a compiler where `i = i++;` would format their hard drive, should I recommend to use such code then? Bug report? There is no bug - C++ does not require compilers to reject all ill-formed programs. There is nothing in C++ standard that says to reject using `std::end()` with VLA

Comment: @Slava I have no idea what point you are trying to make. VLAs are compiler extensions. They are non-standard. They are not undefined behavior, either - they are implementation-defined deviation from standard behavior. Your example of **undefined behavior** have no relevance whatsoever. Btw, if compiler doesn't support VLA, accepting a program where array size is not a constant expression would certainly qualify as a bug in that compiler.

Comment: " I have no idea what point you are trying to make" point is, if you cannot guarantee behavior of using VLA in C++ (and you cannot) then you should not recommend to use it. Nobody stops you from using it of course.

Comment: @Slava looks like you read more than is written. Nowhere in my answer I *recommended* using VLAs to anybody. Please re-read my answer.

Comment: Then it should not be an answer but comment. I understand that as a recommendation, OP or somebody, who reads your answer may as well.

Comment: @Slava I see no recommendation there, and that it is a true answer, as it explains what is that OP is using in his question. It also explains that VLAs are not standard. It also mentions that not everybody likes them. If you read it as a recommendation, it is your personal issue, not mine.

Answer (score 0):

> arr[variable] is not a standard c++, how can I fill the array size from the user?

Don't use C Style Arrays! Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) since it is much easier in this case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> arr;

    for (int x; std::cin >> x;)
    {
        arr.push_back(x);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

> Is this considered a conversion to constant or no?

No you are not converting a variable to a constant, you are storing a normal variable's value in a constant. Conversion would probably require a [`const_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast).

Comment: Well, the storing `const` variable part is irrelevant. gcc will allow `int arr[x];` too.